# In C++, what is the difference between 1 and 1i64?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-shift

I'm converting some 32-bit compatible code into 64-bit - and I've hit a snag. I'm compiling a  VS2008 x64 project, and I receive this warning:

```
warning C4334: '<<' : result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits
(was 64-bit shift intended?)
```

Here's the original line of code:

```
if ((j & (1 << k)) != 0) {
```

And here's what it looks like if I follow [Microsoft's advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke55d167.aspx):

```
if ((j & (1i64 << k)) != 0) {
```

Is this safe to do, when the code will be compiled on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems? If so, please explain why I must add "i64" to the end, and why this will not affect a 32-bit compilation. Otherwise, a work-around would be much appreciated.

Beyond this, I have what looks like an even trickier bit of code.

```
if (id[j] != id[j ^ (1u << k)]) {
```

I understand that the "u" means that the digit is unsigned, but what's the point in specifying that on a value that doesn't exceed the signed maximum value... I'm guessing this has something to do with the bit shift?

Comment: What are the types of j and k?

Comment: so what would be the right *multiplatform* answer? Is possible to change the current answer?

Comment: Which answer do you think is best?

Comment: I would change `1` to `static_cast<size_t>(1)`: 1) this removes the warning. 2) the continues to behave in exactly the same way as it did before and as expected (at least on MSVC 32bit and 64bit). 3) the code behaves as it should. 4) it's cross-plattform C++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`1` has type `int` according to C++ Standard. On 64-bit Microsoft compiler `int` has sizeof = 4 bytes, it means that `int` is 32-bit variable. `1i64` has type `__int64`.

When you use shift operator the type of the result is the same as the type of the left operand. It means that shifting `1` you'll get 32-bit result. Microsoft compiler assumes that it could be not what you are expecting (on 64-bit platform) and gives you warning message.

When you use `1i64` result will be 64-bit on both platforms. `j` and `0` will be implicitly casted to 64-bit. So the whole expression will be calculated in 64-bit variables and result will be `bool`.

So using `1i64` is safe on both (32/64) platforms.

Comment: It not only assumes so, it deduces the need of a 64 bit conversion from the second argument of the "and" operator.  size_t is, indeed, 64 bit on a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: Surely it deduces. The fact that it is `size_t` became public only three hours ago :)

Comment: 1i64 is only safe on MSVC platforms - it is not supported by other compilers or by the standard.

Answer (score 4):

The `i64` suffix is Microsoft-specific.  To be more portable (if you're worried about that), you might use the `INT64_C()` macro from `stdint.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// ...

if ((j & (INT64_C( 1) << k)) != 0) { ... }
```

Unfortunately, MS doesn't have `stdint.h` as part of their C library (most other compilers seem to have it), but fortunately you can get one from several sources:

- http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/
- http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h
- http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h

Now you'll have a 64-bit constant that'll work with a wide variety of compilers.

As far as why you might want or need the 64-bit value, it depends on the types of the various parts of the expression.  It would be helpful to know the types of `id`, `j`, and `k` to be able to answer whether you need the the '`u`' suffix on the constant or not, and what effect it might have.

Comment: as far as I know, that header is part of C99, which means it is *not* part of C++. So it is no more portable than Microsoft's extension.

Comment: I guess you're right.  Still it feels more portable to me. Maybe one could think of it as your own set of macros & types that aid in portability (kind of like the `U8`, `U32` or `INT16` macros you often see, especially in embedded programs), except that they're in more widespread, uniform use. Or like POSIX types which aren't part of the C/C++ standard, but are still often portable, even to Windows compilers. If it's any help, stdint.h is going to be in C++0x.

Comment: Further, INT64_C() isn't a macro in the standard version of `<stdint.h>`, also rendering it not portable.

Comment: @Jonathan - are you sure? Am I misunderstanding 7.18.4.1: "The macro INTN_C(value) shall expand to a signed integer constant with the specified value and type int_leastN_t." Note: the N specifies the width, and 64 is required (by 7.18.1.2).

Comment: Also, I added a qualification to 'portable' in the answer, which should make it a bit more accurate, even if it's still not acceptable :)

Comment: You can also cast the 1 to 64-bit. Like this: `(uint64_t)1 << k`

Answer (score 1):

1i64 I believe should be a signed, 64-bit integer. I can't proclaim any expertise in Microsoft's implementation, but in GCC, the solution for supporting 64-bit integers on 32-bit CPUs was to make long longs double-words using structs and various black magic macros. Therefore, i64 *should* be compatible.

As to the last bit of voodoo -- the only point in specifying 1u it is because it's possible that if k is large enough, the result of the shift would meet / exceed 32-bits of storage, in which case the outcome will be different if the LH operand is treated as a signed or an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

Since that code is 'and'ing the 64-bit variable `j` with the (32-bit) result of a bit-shift, the result will be 'expanded' to 64 bit by the compiler.

You probably want to be in control of how the second operand to the 'and' is calculated, so the compiler suggests you use the full 64 bits by making the first operand an `__int64`.  This is safe in 32 bit, but you should actually look at the type of `j` to decide on the operator being 32 or 64 bit.

That's especially important in the second bit, where the result is used as an index.