# What do i64 and i32 at the end of the values in limits.h mean?

Tags: c

I was looking at limits.h on windows and found this:

```
#define LLONG_MAX     9223372036854775807i64       // maximum signed long long int value
#define LLONG_MIN   (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)  // minimum signed long long int value
#define ULLONG_MAX    0xffffffffffffffffui64       // maximum unsigned long long int value
```

What does the `i64` at the end of the value mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++, what is the difference between 1 and 1i64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264059/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-1i64)

Comment: It is another way to spell `LL`, the postfix you need to tell the compiler that the literal is a 64-bit number.  LL == long long.  `ULL` is the alternative for ui64.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `i64` suffix is a Microsoft extension to specify 64-bit integer constants.

A portable alternative is `(int64_t)9223372036854775807`, but older versions of Microsoft C did not support C99 `<stdint.h>` types.

You can also use the standard suffix `LL` to specify a constant of of type `long long`, which has at least 63 value bits, but may have more on some platforms. The case of `L` is not significant, so `1ll` is equivalent to `1LL`, but significantly more confusing because `l` looks a lot like `1`, especially with some fixed type fonts.

Note that `9223372036854775807` as an integer constant has the smallest type with enough range to express it in the list `int`, `long int`, `long long int`. Given the common sizes for these types on Microsoft platforms, the type `long long int` is probably the only one with 64-bits.

The suffix is more useful for smaller constants such as `1` as show below:

```
uint64_t x = 1 << 32;     // undefined behavior
uint64_t x = 1ULL << 32;  // fully defined, x is 0x800000000
uint64_t x = 1ui64 << 32; // Microsoft specific, non portable
```